# Common variable in Django model's class Meta

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem with varaibles scope. 
Code:

```
class Report(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_fields = []
    class Meta:
        model = ReportData
        fields = self.main_fields

class OtherReport(ReportData):
    fields_to_base_class = ['somefields']

class OtherReport2(ReportData):
    fields_to_base_class = ['othersomefields']
```

How can I do this? Django doesn't see main_fields in Meta.

Comment: Try to be more specific regarding the error your code yields. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is `ReportData`? what does it contain?

Comment: Yes, that's supposed to happen.  `Meta` needs to exist when the class is created, but `self` doesn't exist until the class is instantiated.  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Plus, this isn't a model class, but a FilterSet which isn't even part of Django itself.

Comment: I changed the title of the question because Django's `Meta` class is not a *metaclass*. The original title was confusing between both these terms.